# Plotting sequences with same label, and color in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

I have a set of sequences to plot. All of them should be plotted on the same diagram, but some of them should have same label, and colour.

Using the below code, each sequence would have it's own label, and colour.

```
plt.clf()
for j in range(k)
    plt.plot(lower_graphs[j, :], label=str(alphas_vis[i]))
    plt.plot(upper_graphs[j, :], label=str(alphas_vis[i]))
plt.lengend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: It's a little unclear what exactly is your problem, because obviously you have an array of labels which is good for you, and so you could also generate an array of colours which suits your needs and use this in your loop, too.

Comment: Your'e right, I have an array of labels, by plt cannot understand if I use the same label for different sequences. e.g. if I use label "l" for two sequence "s1", "s2", instead assigning a single label for both, plt assign two different "l" label for each of them; which is not the case.

Comment: @AhmadAsghariyanRezayi I suggest reading [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your data structure is still not clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, now I understand. So you want to have matplotlib to color your plots automatically, but lines with equal label should share color and legend entry. What you can do is to iterate over all lines and labels after creating the plot. And every Label which is already there gets the same Color while it's legend entry is surpressed by a preceding underline. (Labels with '_' at the beginnning are not shown in the auto-legend) :

```
names = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'd']    # sample labels
fig = plt.figure()                        # save your figure in a variable for later access
for i in range(5):
    plt.plot([0,1], [i,i], label=names[i])

plt.legend()                              # still wrong legend for comparison purpose

ax = fig.gca()                            # get the current axis

for i, p in enumerate(ax.get_lines()):    # this is the loop to change Labels and colors
    if p.get_label() in names[:i]:    # check for Name already exists
        idx = names.index(p.get_label())       # find ist index
        p.set_c(ax.get_lines()[idx].get_c())   # set color
        p.set_label('_' + p.get_label())       # hide label in auto-legend
plt.legend(loc='center')                              # correct legend
```

before loop:

[image]

after loop:

[image]

Comment: However, this is the most difficult way to do this. Thanks for your answer, and thanks for your effort.

Comment: As I said in the other answer: this the general case. I had to guess a lot so I think the other answer fits more to your needs.

Answer (score 2):

No, *now* I understand... :-)

If you have two fixed sets of sequences (i.e. 'upper' and 'lower') and you know that one legend entry is always representing one in each set, you could just Label the one set and color the other manually, so your code changes to:

```
for j in range(k)
    p = plt.plot(lower_graphs[j, :], label=str(alphas_vis[i]))
    plt.plot(upper_graphs[j, :], c=p[0].get_c()))
plt.legend()
```

The other answer below is for the more general case, where you can arbitrarily set any sequence to an equal name like any other.